# "Unfortunately app has stopped. Report | OK " dialog opens and closes immediately

Tags: android, beta-testing

I'm beta testing my app. Downloaded the app from play store and opened it, at one point I get

> "Unfortunately app has stopped. Report | OK "

dialog box. I want to hit "Report" and see the trace in Crashes&Anrs on developer console. But the dialog box closes immediately, it's impossible to press the button. How can I report it now?

Comment: The stacktrace wont be available now. I think you have to recreate the error to be able to send it to google play

Comment: I recreated several times. Every time the dialog closes too soon